# When converting column in df to factor replaces with NA

Tags: r

I have a column in a df which is filled with `0` and `1`.

```
pf$mobile_check_in <- NA
pf$mobile_check_in <- ifelse(pf$mobile_likes > 0, 1, 0)
```

When I do this:

```
pf$mobile_check_in <- factor(mobile_check_in)
```

It replaces all the values with `NA`.

Why is it replacing all the values with `NA`?

Comment: Because there is no 0 and 1 in "pf$mobile_check_in".

Comment: @Pascal Sure there is :)

Comment: Not with the code you provide in the example, as mobile_likes is not defined.

Comment: @Pascal see the answer which solved the problem...

Comment: I just point out your example is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line to convert to factors is wrong because you are not using the `pf` as object. Change it to the following:

`pf$mobile_check_in <- factor(pf$mobile_check_in)`

(notice the `pf$` before the mobile_check_in)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh dear... I was staring at that for aaages. Thanks!